# Android Studio update breaks Gradle again

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So, like an idiot, I upgraded Android Studio.

And my project immediately stopped building because of gradle errors.

It says

```
12:06   Gradle sync started with single-variant sync

12:06   Gradle sync failed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 5.1.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/phil/Documents/PATH-TO-PROJECT/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip (245 ms)

12:06   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version=20.0.5594570
```

So I look in gradle-wrapper.properties and it does indeed say

```
#Wed Oct 30 11:57:04 BRT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

So the error message, if I'm interpreting it correctly says "change the gradle-wrapper.properties to refer to gradle-5.4.1" and, indeed, that's what the gradle-wrapper.properties DO refer to.

So I'm guessing this is an ambiguous error message or I'm just being stupid reading it.

Maybe although the error message is telling me to change TO 5.4.1, what it should really be telling me is either

a) **upgrade** my gradle to 5.4.1 because it's currently only 5.1.1.

If so, where do I do this? I never installed gradle myself. I just got it as part of the Android Studio bundle. So where in that Android Studio download can I do this?

or maybe

b) Android Studio automatically updated my gradle-wrapper.properties to 5.4.1, but really I need to change that properties file **BACK** to 5.1.1 because that's what I have installed.

How should I interpret and understand this problem?

I'm not really looking for a "magic spell" of "change these things" or "I cleaned my project and it worked for me".

I'm looking for a short but comprehensive *explanation* as to why these gradle incompatibility problems keep happening in Android Studio. So that I can understand what's actually going on and how to solve these things myself.

Answer (score 1):

Update the Gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to`5.4.1` and let it download that version. It doesn't matter what is globally installed, when using the wrapper (which fetches whatever is being requested). This is happening because the current build-tools plug-in (which has the same version as Android Studio) depends on Gradle >= `5.4.1`. In directory `~/.gradle` one often can remove old wrapper installations; keeping all projects at the same Grade version requires the least space on disk (since it keeps all Gradle versions ever built with, per user).

Alternatively, you could install Gradle >= `5.4.1` globally, eg. `/opt/gradle/5.4.1` and remove the wrapper - but when being the only user on a computer, this is of no real advance, because manual updating is required.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like it could be the beginning of something helpful. But as I said in my question, the gradle-wrapper.properties file DOES say 5.4.1 ... but Android Studio isn't going away and downloading that behind the scenes. It's just giving me the error and stopping

Comment: Would it be sensible to delete .gradle in my home directory and see if things would sort themselves out? Or would this just cause more trouble?

Comment: Make sure to use the wrapper instead of the global installation. wrong permissions can also cause downloads to fail. version `5.1.1` needs to come from somewhere, which is likely a global installation.

Comment: How do I know where 5.1.1 comes from? I can see in my .gradle/wrapper/dists/ a gradle-5.1.1-all directory. Is it there? Can I delete that?

Comment: And how do I set where I'm using the wrapper rather than a global installation?

Comment: That's weird ... I removed the 5.1.1 from my .gradle/wrapper/dists and gradle downloaded itself again ... version 5.1.1 ... so it must be picking that version number up from somewhere else. Because gradle-wrapper.properties definitely says 5.4.1 ...any idea where else Android Studio might keep this number?

Comment: Even weirder. I looks, now, like it wasn't saving the change. When I went outside Android Studio and edited the gradle-wrapper.properties in another editor, to be 5.4.1 then it DID download that new version of gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated Gradle and got a similar error.

In gradle-wrapper.properties, I changed

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

tried to build, then changed it back again, and it built.